# The dialog is run again if the user types something during a delay

Tags: node.js, botframework

When I set a delay between two messages in a waterfall dialog and the user types something before the delay finishes, the dialog step - including the delay - is run again and the delay is repeated.

```js
class Delay extends ComponentDialog {

  constructor(id) {
    super(id);

    this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATER_FALL_DIALOG_ID, [
      this.startStep.bind(this),
      this.delay.bind(this),
      this.endStep.bind(this)
    ]));
  }

  async startStep(stepContext) {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity('Start Delay dialog');
    return await stepContext.next();
  }

  async delay(stepContext) {

    await stepContext.context.sendActivities([
      { type: ActivityTypes.Message, text: 'message 1' },
      { type: 'delay', value: 5000 },
      { type: ActivityTypes.Message, text: 'message 2' }
    ]);

    return stepContext.next();
  }

  async endStep(stepContext) {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity('End Delay dialog');
    return await stepContext.endDialog();
  }
}
```

[image]

I want to know how I can have the bot ignore any inputs during the delay step, or at least not repeat the delay step and messages.

I like that the bot ignores the messages sent from the user during the delay and doesn't take any other action, I just don't want it to repeat the delay step.

Comment: I think this is happening because your dialog is all programmatic. There are no prompts, it's just running its course. When you type an input while the bot is in your delay stage, it seems it doesn't know what to do (because it's not expecting input) so it just repeats the step. What exactly is the purpose of this dialog and the delay? Generally waterfall dialogs are expected to have prompts for user input.

Comment: @billoverton I want to send to the user suggestions, each suggestion contains several messages that I want send with a delay between them. After sending the suggestion I want to ask the user if want more suggestions and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I can see WHY you would want something like this, but the purpose of a bot is to accept input from a user, and reply to it, so there really isn't an official way to have a bot ignore input from user. I would recommend you add a message to your dialog flow along the lines of 'Getting results, please wait', then another message to indicate that your bot is ready to accept input again "Here's what I found. Is there another XYZ you're looking for?"

That being said, if you're using webchat as the channel, there is a way to hide the input box. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2427 This could be an option, but it only works for  webchat, and other channels do not support this particular functionality.